# Redirect url to another url with query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect with .htaccess

http://www.site1.com/pages/?url=http://www.gooogle.com/xyz/jkjk.html

to

http://tracking.site2.com/s?key=123456789&url=http://www.gooogle.com/xyz/jkjk.html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/pages/?$
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^url=(.+)$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ http://tracking.site2.com/s?key=123456789&url=$1  [R=301,L]
```

Tried this.. failed.
Please help me with this

Comment: What do you mean by "failed"? What problems do you get with this rule?

Comment: it is not redirecting. it is redirecting to url like this http://tracking.site2.com/pages/(no query strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess of server1:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ http://tracking.site2.com/s?key=123456789&url=%1 [QSA,NC,NE,R=301,L]
```

Fro back referencing captured group from `RewriteCond` we need to use `%1`, `%2` etc instead of `$1`, `$2`.

Comment: working perfectly. Thank you. is it possible to make http://www.site1.com/pages/xyz/jkjk.html to 
http://tracking.site2.com/s?key=123456789&url=http://www.gooogle.com/xyz/jkjk.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want the query string, add an additional flag of QSA (Query String Append) like so: [R=301,QSA,L]